# My ID got inactive or inactivated?

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, past-tense, participles

I am trying to understand -- after `got`, should the verb be in past tense?

Example:

- got done or did
- got shift or shifted
- got move or moved
- I got confuse or confused

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends but got inactive is not very good. **My ID was deactivated**.\\got in two of your examples means: became. So, got confused nd got shifted.  get/got done is a completely different meaning. And I don't know what you mean with got moved. was moved? Your questions are three questions, basically.

Answer (score 2):

I would say "My ID was deactivated" (or "My ID got deactivated") if it was a **deliberate** act on the part of security personnel.  It may also suggest that it will be impossible (you left the company) or difficult (you did something bad) to get it reactivated.

"My ID became/went inactive" suggests that you did not use it for a while or complete some of the regular required steps to keep it active, and the **system automatically** made your card inactive, prompting you to do some needed updates (e.g., new information, or just a yearly check-in to confirm your details, as I have to do with my library card, even though I use it every week).

To answer your more general question - use:
It got done / shifted / moved / confused
**never** It got did / shift / move / confuse

Answer (score 0):

When you use **get** like this, you are talking about something that happened to something: it's a kind of passive voice sentence.

> I need to activate my credit card - *active voice*
> My credit card needs to be activated - *passive voice*
> My credit card was activated - *passive voice, past*
> My credit card got activated - *passive voice, past*

In passive voice sentences, whether using **was** or **got**, we use the past participle, which ends with **-ed**.

Not all **get** sentences are passive voice: there are a few phrasal verbs that relate to actively doing something, for example **get ready**.

If we are talking about the state of something now or in the past, we use an adjective:

> My credit card is active - *present*
> My credit card was active - *past*

It's a little bit confusing, because past participles are a kind of adjective and we can use some of them in state sentences, so we can say

> My card is **damaged**

We only do this when there is no corresponding adjective... in this case, there is no adjective **damage**- only a verb or a noun. We would not, however, use **activated**, because we can use the adjective form **active**.

So, we can use past participles in **is** sentences is there is no equivalent regular adjective, but we cannot ever use a regular adjective in a passive-voice type **get** sentence.

---

Note that, for a security ID, we would normally say **deactivated** rather than **inactivated**.